# Change something on a page with a function from a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am trying to build a website which will be used to project images on different frames.
Although, I am able to change things (images / text) across different frames, I need to understand whether I can change the same things across different webpages.

Scenario

Page_1
Has a feed of different images as they are uploaded into a mysql database.
e.g. image1, image2, image3.

Page_2
Has a large image (main_image)

Problem
I need to write a function that will change main_image on Page_2 to image1 when I click on image1 on Page_1. I did this across frames using the parents functionality.

```
Page 1                Page 2

--------------      ------------
|             |     | image1   |
| main_image  |     | image2   |
|             |     | image3   |
---------------     ------------
```

and when the user clicks on image1 on Page_2, the output should be -

```
Page 1                Page 2
--------------      ------------
|             |     | image1   |
| image1      |     | image2   |
|             |     | image3   |
---------------     ------------
```

Also, would it be possible if Page_1 and Page_2 are displayed on different computers?

Comment: If they're displaying on different computers then they're completely unrelated, and can't communicate with each other.

Comment: It would be possible if they are on the same site.  Recurring ajax calls to the database figure out what image to display.  Update the database when a different image is chosen.  I wrote a web presentation thing for work that does exactly this.  This question is quite broad, though and needs some attention.

Comment: @Buggabill. I am doing this to develop a presentation platform to project real-time data on the browser window. Perhaps a bit similar to what you had done.. The ajax calls seems to be a good idea. Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the second window from the first one with javascript you can use the returned object to call javascript functions in the opened window.

Pseudocode example, in window1.html javascript:

```
var w = window.open("/window2.html");
w.showDifferentPic();
```

in window2.html javascript:

```
function showDifferentPic() {
    // show picture;
}
```

This only works one a single client, obviously.

It is possible to do across clients, but that is a different story entirely.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be possible on different computers, but using `window.open()` you can open the next page, when you click on image 1.